# Scanner Methods: next() vs nextLine()

Tags: java

I'll admit, I've gone through quite a few (similar) questions, but I can't seem to comprehend the contextual usage in the following piece of code I wrote for an elementary SPOJ problem (http://www.spoj.com/problems/ONP/):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Stack; 
import java.util.Scanner;


public class onp1 {

    public static String postfixString(String expression) {

        // Stack <Character> valueStack = new Stack <Character>();
        Stack <Character> operatorStack = new Stack <Character>();
        String output = "";
        char[] tokens = expression.toCharArray();

        for(char c : tokens) {

            if(c == '('){
                continue;
            }

            else if(c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '^') {
                operatorStack.push(c);
                continue;
            }

            else if(c == ')') {
                output += operatorStack.pop();

                continue;
            }

            else {
                    output += String.valueOf(c);
                continue;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
    public static void main (String [] args)throws java.lang.Exception {

        String inputString = "";
        int n1;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        try
        {
            n1 = in.nextInt();
            StringBuilder[] sb = new StringBuilder[n1];
            for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {

                sb[i] = new StringBuilder();



                inputString = in.next();

                sb[i].append(postfixString(inputString)); 

            }


            for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(sb[i]));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           // System.out.println("");
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());    
            // numberOfTestCases.next();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

If I use nextLine() instead of next(), the SPOJ engine generates a 'Wrong Answer' response.

Also, there seems to be some issue while using a StringBuilder object instead of a String object in the postfixString function (I was using a StringBuilder object earlier; was returning a string using the 'toString()' method).

Please ignore the logical inconsistencies (I know there are a few). I've already ironed (most) of them out. What's driving me crazy are `nextLine()` vs `next()` and StringBuilder vs String issues.

Comment: "I can't seem to comprehend the contextual usage" I don't understand what you're asking. `next()` returns the next token (separated by whitespace, by default), and `nextLine()` returns the next line. Unless you show us the code with and without `StringBuilder` I don't see how anyone can help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

`next()` will only return what comes before a space. `nextLine()` returns the current line and moves the scanner down to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

if you have space in between your input String like "(a + b) * c" then `next` method will give ( followed by a then + then b.

While if you use `nextLine` it will read whole line at once.

String is an immutable class while StringBuilder isn't. Meaning String once created can't be change. So moment you do "str1" + "str2", it creates three string object, "str1" then "str2" and then "str1str2". While if you use StringBuilder's `append` method, you just keep on adding to same object and then at final once when you are done appending the strings, you call `toString` on StringBuilder to create final String object just once.